# SQLite: Does .dump copy or recreate indexes?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, parallel-processing, copy, dump

I am using the `sqlite3` command `.dump` like so:

```
sqlite3 infile.db ".dump my_table" | sqlite3 outfile.db
```

At first I thought I had finally found a way to copy (among others) indexes, which would be great for parallel processing reasons.

But now it seems to me that the indexes are merely recreated as the `sqlite3 infile.db` process is long finished while the `sqlite3 outfile.db` process is still running at 100% CPU.

Comment: .dump outputs create table, insert, create index, create view, etc. DDL statements.

Comment: Maybe you want .backup instead.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the correct answer. Maybe you want to post it as such?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: The command `.dump` recreates the indexes on the copied tables. It does not copy the indexes.

Indexes are copied using the `.backup` command, but this does not support addressing single tables.